# Docusign configuration in Salesforce error

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

Ive been advised by Docusign to post here. 
I have 4 clients who I've installed the Docusign for Salesforce App for.  I've followed the installation instructions and every time I end up with the same error.  When it comes to entering my Salesforce credentials it says they are wrong or I have not added the trusted network.  I know the credentials are correct and I have entered the trusted network.  I've tried various things like using security token in the password, configuring at the docusign end.  Nothing works, Docusign don't know what the issue is, I've also raised a case with Salesforce and they can't help.  I can't understand why an App on the app exchange can't get passed configuration and noone can help!  Hopefully someone here can help.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The DocuSignAPI tag on Stack Overflow is used for api development and integration questions normally, however I will try to address your issue...

First off, if you could update your question with a screenshot of the error and screen you are on when you receive the error that would help isolate the issue.

With that in mind, what screen are you on?  Are you on the screen that's titled "Connect DocuSign to Salesforce"?  Even though you've mentioned I just want to double check that you are entering your Salesforce user credentials and not your DocuSign credentials.

Next, what environment are you selecting?  And what type of DocuSign account do you have?  You need to make sure that you are pointing to an environment where you have an existing account.  For instance, if you have a DocuSign demo account but you are pointing to Production during the install, you might get that error.